# Calling apply on empty DataFrame on axis="columns" loops through 2 Series?

Tags: pandas

The following

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame([], columns=["a", "b", "c"]).apply(lambda row: print(row), axis=1)
```

prints

```
Series([], dtype: float64)
Series([], dtype: float64)
```

Is this a feature or a bug?
This breaks some of my code when the DataFrame is empty because I expected apply to be like a loop that loops through the records, but it seems it does something different?
Any way to make this behave more like a loop?

Comment: First line is from `print(row)` and second line is the result (returned Series) from `apply`.

Comment: Hi @Emma! :) Now the question is: why does this return one record still?

Comment: IIRC, apply does a dry run of the function once for some book-keeping stuff. I thought this is fixed in recent pandas releases.

Comment: I'm using pandas@1.3.3 (current is 1.3.4), so I guess this is not fixed?
I'll open an issue on GH

Comment: Opened issue on GH: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44090